# First time developer at Dreamforce

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

This will be my first visit to dream force. I have a Salesforce developer role Can you please give me a few pointers so I get the most benefits from attending.

I plan to register in the developer centric events when registration opens but can you please suggest some topics that you think are useful. Is there anything else I can look forward to like special sessions or keynotes I should not miss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There will be more developer based sessions than you count so the real trick is picking out the ones that are related to what you're doing right now work wise, or what you might be doing in the next 12 months.

That said, the developer keynote is a must!

Comment: I agree on the developer keynote!

Comment: Thanks guys. The registration has opened. When is the developer keynote happening? Thanks!

Comment: Developer keynote might not have been visible then, it's at 10:30am on the Wednesday

Comment: Yup..Registered thanks!

Comment: I also registered for the stackexchange session you are presenting. Looking forward to meeting you all.

Answer (score 5):

I actually just released a blog post about this exact topic - http://jessealtman.com/2013/10/new-to-dreamforce-developers-perspective/.

---

- [Dreamforce FAQ](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/help.jsp) provides a ton of great information
- Join the discussion on Twitter using the [#df13](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23df13&src=hash) hashtag and follow [@Dreamforce](https://twitter.com/Dreamforce)
- When building your [agenda](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/agenda.jsp) be sure to take into consideration time to eat lunch, time to travel (check the location of each session - again, this conference is HUGE and traveling takes time!), and time to socialize
  - Under each session in the Agenda Builder, there is a Location accordion that can be expanded to view the layout of the conference to the location of the session.
- Give yourself some time to experience the [Expo](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/cloud-expo.jsp)
  - Not attending? No problem! [Get a FREE Keynote & Expo Pass](https://www.salesforce.com/form/dreamforce/free/keynote-expo-df13.jsp?d=70130000000tXbA)
- Dreamforce is a ton of fun and that means [parties](http://dfguide.com/)! Make sure you get a chance to get to some of these
- Get [certified for half price](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/training.jsp) on Monday Nov. 18th
- Show up to sessions early! It could take as long as 5-10mins to get into a session (you have to be registered and they will scan your Dreamforce badge to verify)
- Wear comfortable shoes. You will be walking all day, each day.
- See [Green Day](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/socialize.jsp) perform at AT&T park as part of your conference pass
- On the My Agenda tab of the [Dreamforce App](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcloudevent.secure.force.com%2Flogin&ei=ZedaUq7oCO-44APE9oCgDg&usg=AFQjCNGse_2m8x9foB7To1XL76-e4dCXEw&sig2=hcZZ57uI762a_ErLepS_cw&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg), you can download your agenda as [PDF](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/apex/DownloadAgenda) or [Outlook/iCal](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/apex/iCal)
- Get involved in [Dreamforce's Chatter](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/apex/Chatter)
  - Specifically, join the [New to Dreamforce '13](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/apex/Chatter#page=groups&group=0F930000000D2v2CAC) Chatter group

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Are you already following the New `to Dreamforce 13` ([url](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F930000000D2v2)) chatter group on the dreamforce org ?

You're definitely not the only one with these questions, I'm going for the first time too.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I attend a conference I try to follow some simple guidelines:

1. Don't stack sessions too closely together or too many in one day
2. Attend "stretch" sessions that I think are probably beyond my skill level but will introduce me to new things
3. Attend some sessions for other job functions; sometimes seeing how others use a system helps me understand my users better and offer better solutions
4. Visit the expo; you might find something that makes your life (or your company's business) **way** better
5. Network. Talking to others is a great way to learn the capabilities of the system and help each other out

Dreamforce specific:

1. Visit the Dev Zone
2. Attend the True to the Core keynote.
3. Attend the Developer keynote
4. Attend a Hands On Training Session (HOTS) if they look appealing - guided introductions are wonderful!